# How to create something in BeforeTestRun and access it in step definitions

Tags: c#, nhibernate, bdd, specflow

I would like to create an NHibernate session factory once at the start of a SpecFlow test run, and then access it in individual step definitions to call OpenSession() on it.

It seems like a `[BeforeTestRun]` hook would be the best place to set up the session factory.  However I am struggling to see how I can store the session factory and then retrieve it in a particular step definition (most likely part of a `Background` section) in order to get a session and insert some data.

I tried using the SpecFlow container, as follows:

```
[Binding]
public class NhDataSupport
{
    private readonly IObjectContainer objectContainer;

    public NhDataSupport(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
    {
        this.objectContainer = objectContainer;
    }

    [BeforeTestRun]
    public void InitializeSessionFactory()
    {
        var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("SqlServerDataTesting")))
            .Mappings(cfg =>
                cfg.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<HostMap>()
            )
            .BuildSessionFactory();

            objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<ISessionFactory>(sessionFactory);
    }
}
```

...so that other `[Binding]` classes could be passed the session factory via constructor injection, I hoped.  But this gets a

> System.Reflection.TargetException, Non-static method requires a target.

I'm guessing that's because (as I learned from the [SpecFlow docs](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Hooks/)), the method `[BeforeTestRun]` is applied to must be static.

Is there a way of achieving this, configuring the SessionFactory once but calling OpenSession on it from other Binding classes?  I don't want to build the session factory for every scenario, as this is an expensive operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public class SessionFactoryHolder
{
    private static ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static void SetupNhibernateSessionFactory()
    {
        sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                                 .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("SqlServerDataTesting")))
                                 .Mappings(cfg => cfg.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<HostMap>()            )
        .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get { return sessionFactory; }
    }
}

[Binding]
public class Binding
{
     [BeforeTestRun]
     public static void SetupNhibernateSessionFactory()
     {
         SessionFactoryHolder.SetupNhibernateSessionFactory();
     }
}
```

Now you can access the SessionFactory when you let SpecFlow inject the SessionFactoryHolder via constructor.

It is similar to @ngm solution, but you can spare to get the "internal" IObjectContainer from SpecFlow.

See here http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Context-Injection/ for more infos about context injection in SpecFlow.

Notice: code written by head, not tried to compile, so there could be typos.

Answer (score 4):

The following works.

- Use a static field on a non-static `[Binding]`-annotated class.
- In  `[BeforeTestRun]`, do the work (in my case building the `SessionFactory`) and assign the result to the static field.
- In `[BeforeScenario]`, register the static field instance with the container.

Not sure if it's best practice, but it does work.

```
[Binding]
public class DataHooks
{
    private readonly IObjectContainer objectContainer;
    private static ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public DataHooks(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
    {
        this.objectContainer = objectContainer;
    }

    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void SetupNhibernateSessionFactory()
    {
        sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("SqlServerDataTesting")))
            .Mappings(cfg =>
                cfg.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<HostMap>()
            )
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void BeforeScenario()
    {
        objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<ISessionFactory>(sessionFactory);
    }
}
```

The session factory is then available in any `[Binding]`-annotated class via constructor injection of `ISessionFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not specific to NHibernate I ran into a similar issue trying to maintain authorization throughout a entire test run of API tests. I ended up using a singleton pattern for my rest client using the [BeforeScenario] tag. While this isn't [BeforeTestRun] that this question is asking about and the object will still be registered before each scenario, the amount of times the client is created is still limited to once. I would imagine you could apply a similar approach to NHibernate.

```
[Binding]
public class RestClientInjector
{
    private readonly IObjectContainer objectContainer;
    public RestClientInjector(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
    {
        this.objectContainer = objectContainer;
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void InitializeRestClient()
    {
        RestClient client = SingletonRestClient.getInstance();
        objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<RestClient>(client);
    }

    // implelent singleton

    public class SingletonRestClient
    {
        private static RestClient client = new RestClient();

        private SingletonRestClient(IObjectContainer objectContainer) {}

        public static RestClient getInstance()
        {
            return client;
        }
    }
}
```